# Animation for image inside the Button

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular2-template

I am new to this coding field, I think my issue is simple for experienced people like you all guys.I am trying to animate the image which is inside the button.When I click on the button I need the image to be rotated 360deg.I dont know what wrong I am  doing here is my HTML and CSS code.Please help

```css
.syncRotate {
  -webkit-transition: 500ms ease all !important;
  -moz-transition: 500ms ease all !important;
  -o-transition: 500ms ease all !important;
  transition: 500ms ease all !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="iconBtn" mdTooltipPosition="above" mdTooltip="Sync User" (click)="sync()">
    <img class="syncRotate" style="width:20px;background-color: #a6a6a6;border-radius: 13px;padding:2px;" src="../../assets/images/icons/sync.svg" alt="Sync">
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you if you only want it using **transition.!**

```css
.syncRotate {
  -webkit-transition: 500ms ease all;
  -moz-transition: 500ms ease all;
  -o-transition: 500ms ease all;
  transition: 500ms ease all;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.syncRotate:active {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="iconBtn" mdTooltipPosition="above" mdTooltip="Sync User" (click)="sync()">
    <img class="syncRotate" style="width:20px;background-color: #a6a6a6;border-radius: 13px;padding:2px;" src="https://lh6.ggpht.com/bE_u2kFoX28G428YH1jpWTMoaZ3B9cokstrKxD82zj7hoBNL-U1wiAVddau3mvvUpPoD=w300" alt="Sync">
</button>
```

IF you want it to make nice animation using ***CSS animation***

```css
@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.syncRotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.syncRotate:active {
  animation: rotation 500ms ease-in-out forwards;
}
```

```html
<button class="iconBtn" mdTooltipPosition="above" mdTooltip="Sync User" (click)="sync()">
    <img class="syncRotate" style="width:20px;background-color: #a6a6a6;border-radius: 13px;padding:2px;" src="https://lh6.ggpht.com/bE_u2kFoX28G428YH1jpWTMoaZ3B9cokstrKxD82zj7hoBNL-U1wiAVddau3mvvUpPoD=w300" alt="Sync">
</button>
```

BY changing **500ms to 400ms or so we can make it fast** and changing it higher will make the animation and transition **slower eg 900ms or 1s**.

**Note:** Because we are **only using CSS** the animation and transition only last while the user is clicked on the button. SO in your case both will be same.

Comment: Personally I find this not that accurate, the animation will only work as long as the click is pressed, and also, when you click outside of the image but inside of the button, rotation doesn't trigger. It also implicates additional CSS. Last is that :active pseudo class is not exactly the same as click event, it corresponds to the time in between the click is pressed and released.

Comment: @Syden  then please be kind and show us a way of getting the result without **jQuery**

Comment: @Syden  that I know bro. He only needs is it using **CSS** as per his comments. So that's why! and I agree with you on this can attain much better using **JS** or **jQuery**

Comment: @Jithin, I see typescript and angular tags, thats enough JS. Also nowhere in the original post explicitly states no JS which in fact would be the accurate way of doing it.

Comment: @Syden am not sure... But you better ask him.

Comment: It would be better to trigger the transform when the button is active/clicked rather than the image: `.iconBtn:active .syncRotate { transform: rotate(360deg); }`

Answer (score 1):

360deg rotate without click

```css
.syncRotate {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-property: transform;
}
.syncRotate:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="iconBtn" mdTooltipPosition="above" mdTooltip="Sync User" (click)="sync()">
    <img class="syncRotate" style="width:20px;background-color: #a6a6a6;border-radius: 13px;padding:2px;" src="https://lh6.ggpht.com/bE_u2kFoX28G428YH1jpWTMoaZ3B9cokstrKxD82zj7hoBNL-U1wiAVddau3mvvUpPoD=w300" alt="Sync">
</button>
```

Comment: @Dom...I need onClick not on hover. Ty

Answer (score 1):

**Vanilla JS solution**:

1. Add the rotation class to the element with **classList.add()**
2. Remove the rotation class after it's over so next click will rotate as desired with **classList.remove()** inside of **setTimeout()**.
3. You can tweak rotation speed from transition ms time (1500 on demo), make sure to set it's time either equal or higher than the transition time.

```js
document.querySelector(".iconBtn").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector("img").classList.add("syncRotate");
  //remove class after rotation is over so next click will rotate again
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector("img").classList.remove('syncRotate');
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
.syncRotate {
  -webkit-transition: 1500ms ease all;
  -moz-transition: 1500ms ease all;
  -o-transition: 1500ms ease all;
  transition: 1500ms ease all;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="iconBtn" mdTooltipPosition="above" mdTooltip="Sync User" (click)="sync()">
  <img class="image" style="width:20px;background-color: #a6a6a6;border-radius: 13px;padding:2px;" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" alt="Sync">
</button>
```

**jQuery solution**:

1. Add the rotation class to the element with **addClass()**
2. Remove the rotation class after it's over so next click will rotate as desired with **removeClass()** inside of **setTimeout()**.
3. You can tweak rotation speed from transition ms time (1500 on demo), make sure to set it's time either equal or higher than the transition time.

```js
$(".iconBtn").on('click', function() {
    $('img').addClass("syncRotate");
    //remove class after rotation is over so next click will rotate again
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('img').removeClass('syncRotate');
    }, 1500);
});
```

```css
.syncRotate {
  -webkit-transition: 1500ms ease all;
  -moz-transition: 1500ms ease all;
  -o-transition: 1500ms ease all;
  transition: 1500ms ease all;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="iconBtn" mdTooltipPosition="above" mdTooltip="Sync User" (click)="sync()">
  <img class="image" style="width:20px;background-color: #a6a6a6;border-radius: 13px;padding:2px;" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" alt="Sync">
</button>
```

Comment: exactly the same code i have by using jQuery. But I need to do in TypeScript.

Comment: @Musheer, typescript compiles to vanilla JS, you can load the first solution on a script.js file without jQuery (you can even remove it altogether if you don't use it on other stuff).